# Plotting the region in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How to plot the region $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z^2-2| \leq 1\}$ in Complex (argand) plane? This is simple for $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z-2| \leq 1\}$ as it is interior of circle. Is some geometrical interpretation possible for $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z^2-2| \leq 1\}$?

Comment: The solutions to $|z^2-2|\leq 1$ are precisely the square roots of the solutions to $|z-2|\leq 1$, right? (Note that there are two square roots for each nonzero complex number.)

Answer (score 1):

The boundary of this region has $z^2 = 2 + e^{i\theta}$, so $z = \pm \sqrt{2 + e^{i\theta}}$, $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ say.

[image]

These are not circles, but close.

Comment: How to plot $z=\pm\sqrt{2+e^{i\theta}}$?

Comment: If $2+e^{i\theta} = r e^{i \varphi}$ with $r > 0$, $\varphi \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, $\sqrt{2+e^{i\theta}} = \sqrt{r} e^{i \varphi/2} = \sqrt{r} \cos(\varphi/2) + i \sqrt{r} \sin(\varphi/2)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [Cassini oval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval), a [Lemniscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_lemniscate) for the degree $2$ polynomial $z^2-2$, or rather its interior. It is bounded by the set of points $z$ such that the product $|z-\sqrt{2}|\cdot|z+\sqrt{2}|$ of its distances to the points $\pm\sqrt{2}$ is a constant $1$.

To plot you will need to parameterize it and evaluate a handful of its points.

It is not a conic section but it is a [torus section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval#Cassini_ovals_on_tori), a doughnut intersected with a plane.

In Cartesian coordinates the equation of the boundary is

$$(x^2-y^2-2)^2+4x^2y^2=1$$